# Primary key consists of a foreign key and a identity and should reset identity under a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
create table Linq_TB
{
   url_id int NOTNULL,
   Pg_Name nvarchar(50) NOTNULL,
   URL nvarchar(50) NUTNULL,

   CONSTRAINT Linq_id PRIMARY KEY (url_id,DBCC Checkident(Linq_TB,RESEED,0) case url_id not in(select URL_Id from URL_TB ))
}
```

I want to make a table which it's primary key is `Linq_id` and gets it's value from both the `url_id` and identity with start from 1 and increments 1 by 1. `url_id` is a foreign key. For example if `url_id` is 1, `linq_id`'s will be 11, 12, 13,... and I also want to reset `linq_id` identity when the `url_id` changes.

What should the query be? The query above doesn't work, why?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well, a constraint contains conditions and not code to be executed. You should consider using a stored procedure for your task and also a homegrown method of assigning IDs.

However, it is not a common practice to have your primary keys 'pretty' or formatted, as there is no real benefit (except maybe for debugging purposes maybe).

I do not recommend executing DBCC whenever your url_ID changes. This has a great negative impact on performance.

Why don't you leave the IDs like they are?

Comment: Thanks for ur response,I wanted my tables to be more understandable,but I have noticed it is not wise.

Comment: I understand. To overcome this, declare some views which join the tables together. For all my low level (and -yes- hard to understand tables) I have a corresponding view ('V'+name of table) which shows 'names' instead of Ids.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the following table and trigger definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE Linq_TB
(
   url_id INT NOT NULL,
   Linq_id INT NOT NULL,
   Pg_Name NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   URL NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

   CONSTRAINT PK_Link_TB PRIMARY KEY (url_id, Linq_id),
   CONSTRAINT FK_URL_TB_URL_ID FOREIGN KEY (url_id) REFERENCES URL_TB (url_id)
)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER tr_Linq_TB_InsertUpdate
ON Linq_TB
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
    INSERT INTO Linq_TB
    SELECT i.url_id,
        ISNULL(tb.Linq_id, 0)
            + row_number() over (partition by i.url_id order by (select 1)),
        i.Pg_Name, i.URL
    FROM inserted i
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            (
            SELECT url_id, MAX(Linq_ID) Linq_id
            FROM Linq_TB
            GROUP BY url_id
            ) tb ON i.url_id = tb.url_id
GO
```

The `CREATE TABLE` defines your columns and constraints.  And, the trigger creates the logic to generate a sequence value in your `Linq_id` column for each `url_id`.

Note that the logic in the trigger is not complete.  A couple of issues are not addressed: 1) If the `url_id` changes for a row, the trigger doesn't update the `Link_id`, and 2) deleting rows will lead to gaps in the `Linq_TB` column sequence.

Comment: Thanks for ur response,I don't want to define composite primary key,can't we just set a formula for Linq_id column when making the table?for example Linq_id=[url_id]*10+Identity(1,1)